Angular 18 model() and output() not working
I'm trying to use a ModelSignal in an Angular 18 application but compiler complains with
Can't bind to test since it is not provided by any applicable directives.
I checked the documentation but couldn't find any difference with what I have...
Since I was not able to make ModelSignal work, I tried to use a combination of InputSignal and OutputEmitter but the output one is not recognized.
Node v20.14.0
Angular CLI 18.0.3
Default configuration
My component looks like:
import {Component, input, model, output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent {

  test = model<number>(0);
  in = input<number>(0);
  ou = output<number>();

}

And my parent component's template looks like:
<app-test [in]="1" (ou)="foo($event)" [(test)]="test" />
[in] is properly recognized but both (ou) and [(test)] are not recognized and fail on compilation.
Any clue on why it is not working?

What IDE do you use? If you are using WebStorm make sure you have version 2024.1 or above installed.

@Nifiro  It was that indeed, 2024.1 seems to fail. 2024.1.3 works.

Ok, as @Nifiro suggested,the problem was from the IDE.
I was using WebStorm 2024.1 and updating to WebStorm 2024.1.3 fixed the issue.
Strange that the IDE didn't warn me that an update was available...
